A brief explanation on Representation Theory
I'm trying to read this beautiful paper Regularity and cohomology of determinantal thickenings by Claudiu Raicu but I'm getting in trouble with Representation Theory, since I have no knowledge of it.
These sentences in Section 2.1 are quite mysterious for me.

"For $m\geq n$ we consider the ring $S = Sym(\mathbb{C}^m \otimes \mathbb{C}^n)$ of polynomial functions on the space of complex $m \times n$ matrices, with the natural action by $\mathrm{GL} = \mathrm{GL}_m(\mathbb{C}) \times \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$."

"Cauchy’s identity yields the decomposition of S into irreducible GL-representations
$$ S = \bigoplus_{ \underline{x}\in\mathcal{P}_n} S_\underline{x} (\mathbb{C}^m)  \otimes S_\underline{x}(\mathbb{C}^m), $$
where $S_\underline{x}$ denotes the Schur functor associated to the partition x. By abusing notation we will
write
$$S_\underline{x} =  S_\underline{x} (\mathbb{C}^m)  \otimes S_\underline{x}(\mathbb{C}^m), \text{ so that } S =\sum_{ \underline{x}\in\mathcal{P}_n} S_\underline{x}.$$
Very concretely, we can realize $S_\underline{x}$ as the linear span of the $\mathrm{GL}$-orbit of a highest weight vector as follows..."


Can you give some hints or concrete examples to understand or an introducting book where this topic is discussed? Thank you very much!

Thank you very much for your suggestion! :)

This doesn't explicitly answer your question, but I hope it is helpful. I cannot comment due to being a new user.
The polynomial ring $S=\mathbb{C}[x_{i,j}]$ has a action of $GL$ coming from the natural action on the matrix of variables $(x_{i,j})$, where $GL_m(\mathbb{C})$ acts by multiplication on the left, and $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ acts by multiplication by the inverse on the right (to make it a left action).
As such, $S$ decomposes as a direct sum of irreducible representations of $GL$, which are tensor products of irreducible representations of $GL_m(\mathbb{C})$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. These representations are the Schur modules, which you can read more about in Fulton--Harris or in Weyman's "Cohomology of Vector Bundles and Syzygies", chapter 2. Actually, Weyman chapter 2 has everything you need, including a proof of Cauchy's formula.
For instance, $S_{(d,0,\cdots,0)}\mathbb{C}^m=\operatorname{Sym}^d\mathbb{C}^m$ is the $d$-th symmetric power of $\mathbb{C}^m$, and $S_{(1^d)}\mathbb{C}^m=\bigwedge^d\mathbb{C}^m$ is the $d$-th exterior power of $\mathbb{C}^m$. Here, $(1^d)=(1,\cdots,1)$ is the partition with $d$ ones. More general Schur modules $S_{\underline{x}}\mathbb{C}^m$ are some generalization of these operations.
In Section 2 of Raicu you quote, it is explaining the decomposition of $S$ as a representation of $GL$. In particular, $S$ is "multiplicity-free", meaning that each irreducible appears at most once. Furthermore, $S_{\underline{x}}\mathbb{C}^m\otimes S_{\underline{y}}\mathbb{C}^n$ appears only if $\underline{x}=\underline{y}$. He goes on to describe the "highest weight vector" of each irreducible summand $S_{\underline{x}}$ as "$det_{\underline{x}}$", which is a product of powers of top-left minors. Equivalently, $S_{\underline{x}}$ is the vector subspace of $S$ spanned by the $GL$-orbit of $det_{\underline{x}}$.
As a first exercise, convince yourself that if $m=n$ and $\underline{x}=(t,\cdots,t)=(t^m)$ is the partition consisting of $m$ $t$'s, then $S_{\underline{x}}$ is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by the polynomial $det(x_{i,j})^t$.
As another example, $S_{(1^p)}$ is the subspace of $S$ spanned by the $p\times p$ minors of $(x_{i,j})$.
Every $GL$-invariant ideal in $S$ is generated by finitely many $S_{\underline{x}}$. See "Young Diagrams and Determinantal Varieties" by De Concini--Eisenbud--Procesi for more information about the ideals in the paper you are reading.

Thank you very much! I really appreciated your answer, it is very useful for me :)

Was the following sentence right, or was there a switch?  "For instance, $S_{(d,0,\cdots,0)}\mathbb{C}^m=\operatorname{Sym}^d\mathbb{C}^m$ is the $d$-th symmetric power of $\mathbb{C}^m$, and $S_{(1^d)}\mathbb{C}^m=\bigwedge^d\mathbb{C}^m$ is the $d$-th exterior power of $\mathbb{C}^m$."  I'm reading Weyman's "Cohomology of Vector Bundles and Syzygies", chapter 2. (Example 2.1.3), and it is written that $L_{(t)}(E)=\bigwedge^tE$
, for instance. @mathBoi
